# Formatting data in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How would you format the following data outcome in C#.

[image]

---

My controller class returns the data like the one below; I used Dapper as ORM.

The problem here is it returns the number of teams times teams members (eg, Teams X Team Members)instead of team members within a team;

```
     [HttpGet("GetMyTeamsDemo")]
public async Task <List<JTeam>> GetMyTeamsDemo(int UId)
{
    List<JTeam> teams = new List<JTeam>();      
    JTeam jteam = new JTeam();
    List<JMember> members = new List<JMember>();

    var result = await _userDataStore.GetMyTeams(UId);
    
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        
        jteam.TeamId = item.Id;
        jteam.TeamName = item.TeamName;
        jteam.TeamsCode = item.TeamsCode;
        jteam.Description = item.Description;
        jteam.CreatedById = item.CreatedById;
        jteam.CreatedByName = item.CreatedByName;
        jteam.TeamProfilePhoto = item.TeamProfilePhoto;
        jteam.CoverPhoto = item.CoverPhoto;
        jteam.DateCreated = item.DateCreated;

        var res = await _userDataStore.GetTeamMembersByTeamId(item.Id);
        if (res is not null)
        {
            foreach (var item1 in res)
            {
                members.Add(new JMember { MemberId = item1.MemberId, MemberName = item1.MemberName, TeamId = item1.TeamId });
                //teams.Members.Add(new JTeam.JMember { MemberId = itar.MemberId, MemberName = itar.MemberName, TeamId = itar.TeamId });
                jteam.Members = members;
                teams.Add(jteam);                 
            }
        }
        jteam = new JTeam();
    }
    return teams;
}
 public class JTeam
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string TeamsCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByName { get; set; }
    public string TeamProfilePhoto { get; set; }
    public string CoverPhoto { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public JMember Members { get; set; }       
}
public class JMember
{
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's better if you share what code you're using the get the JSON and then someone can share an answer with you.

Comment: Yes I have added the code her; Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (var item1 in res)
        {
            ...
            jteam.Members = members;
            teams.Add(jteam);                 
        }
```

You are adding the team to the list within the `foreach` for the team members instead of after the members have been added to the team. It's the same object in memory, so when the JSON serializer loops through the "teams" it has multiple references to the same team and adds it multiple times to the JSON.

Move `teams.Add(jteam);` outside of the inner `foreach` loop (and the `if` that contains it).

I would also initialize `jteam` within the loop instead of defining it outside of the loop and resetting it at the end.

Comment: I moved teams.Add(jteam); to outer loop and initialize the  JTeam jteam = new JTeam(); within the first loop; still having same issues.